# Is this possible: Use css from other virtual host?

Tags: nginx, virtualhost, website, css, development

Say I have a website at `/var/www/Electrician`
and I have a website at `/var/www/Restaurant`

If these websites use separate host files can I use the same CSS to reduce space?

If I am not mistaken I would certainly be unable to do ../../css/style.css because the one host is restricted from access the other, I would imagine.

I can see putting the one website into the other website directory, but I see that leaving room for cross-site issues.

I will admit I am doing a poor job explaining this. Essentially I would like to share CSS stylesheets between to separate websites on the same server, which will employ separate host files.

Comment: Perhaps this should be asked at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sharing CSS files to *save space*? There are a lot of potentially good reasons to share CSS files, but "saving space" most likely isn't one. That said, there are *many* ways this can be accomplished, from symlinks to `<location>` statements. However, if you want to save resources, it will be more effective if you share them one level up, e.g. you refer to CSS files on `http://example.com` on your secondary site `http://example.org` - this way the browser can use cached copies for users of both sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple symlinking could do the trick, for example:
/var/www/Electrician/css-stuff -> ../shared-css
/var/www/Restaurant/css-stuff -> ../shared-css
Make sure Apache or whatever is allowed to follow symlinks.

Comment: Oh boy, I should have put more thought into this. I totally overlooked the use of a symbolic link for this. I didn't even think of using the full URL to link to the CSS of the other site. I appreciate your answer very much, thank you!